# How to gain access to newly created point cloud map

Tags: ros, laser-assembler, laser-pipeline, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After successfully running my point cloud data through the laser assembler node and creating a composite map how do I gain access to this new map and send it to different nodes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11393/how-to-gain-access-to-newly-created-point-cloud-map/) by [tyler258](https://answers.ros.org/users/1092/tyler258/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2011-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The laser_assembler node publishes to the `assembled_cloud` topic. You can then subscribe to this topic to gain access to the data in a ROS node. The `assembled_cloud` message is of the type sensor_msgs/PointCloud. You could use something like:

```
cloud_sub_ = node_.subscribe<sensor_msgs::PointCloud> ("/assembled_cloud", 100, &MyNode::CloudCallback, this);
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1